# Counting substrings of a string that do not contain a given string

Tags: strings, substrings, string-matching

Let's say we have a string $s[0..n-1]$ and a pattern $p[0..m-1]$ with $m < n$. I am looking for an $O(nm)$ solution to the following problem: find the number of substrings of $s$ not containing $p$ as a substring. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using dynamic programming.

Define $C(i)$ where $i$ ranges from $0$ to $n$:

$$C(0) = (1, 0)$$

$$
C(i) = \begin{cases}
(C_1(i - 1), 0)  & \text{if $p = s[i - 1 - m ... i - 1]$} \\
(C_1(i-1) + C_2(i-1) + 1, C_2(i-1) + 1)    & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Then $C_1(n)$ contains the answer.

The idea is that $C_1(i)$ denotes the number of found substrings after considering the first $i$ characters and $C_2(i)$ the length of the longest substring ending at $i - 1$ uninterrupted by $p$.

If $p$ ends at $i - 1$, then we cannot add to the number of substrings (because now the substring would contain $p$) and also we must reset the length of the current longest substring to 0.

Otherwise we can increment the length of the current longest substring by 1. Also we add that length to total substring count. In general, summing from $1 + ... + l$ gives all possible substrings of a string of length $l$. Note that this way we therefore sum all possible substrings of all substrings of $s$ not containing $p$.

Computing $C(i)$ takes $O(m)$ if $C(i - 1)$ has already been computed. We compute $C$ from $0$ to $n$, which yields a run-time of $O(nm)$.